# I don't understand dynamic_cast or what?

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I'm a bit newbie in c++ but why this code prints that the queue item is not a child while I created him as a child:

```
class Parent
{
public: virtual const char* getName() { return "Who is your daddy?"; }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public: virtual const char* getName() { return "La gente esta muy loca?"; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::deque<Parent> queue;   
    queue.push_back(Child());
    Parent* p = &queue.back();
    if (dynamic_cast<Child*>(p) == 0) { std::cout << "I am not child"; }
    else { std::cout << "Welcome, son"; }
    std::cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: The deque stores `Parent` instances, *not* pointers or references to them. You don't get polymorphism in C++ without pointers or references, all you did was *convert* your `Child` to a `Parent` instance when you pushed it to the deque, so when you go fetch a pointer to it, it truly is a `Parent`.

Comment: The `deque` holds `Parent` objects so when you push a `Child` on it, it 'forgets' it really holds a `Child` and stores it as a `Parent` instead.  The cast can't know that happened, so you get "I am not a child".  If you store `Parent*` instead, it should function correctly

Comment: Okay, I understand what is slicing, but i don't understand now what should i do to get my child object from queue back? And more over, I don't understand for what dynamic_cast is needed if I can't call child methods anyway

Comment: @MikhailIvanov - you have to store pointers instead so the polymorphism will work correctly.

Comment: @MikhailIvanov You use `dynamic_cast` with pointer or reference types, never with actual object types.